# Does Parse.com encrypt data at rest

Tags: encryption, parse-platform

I have been asked if "I am" encrypting my data at rest.  I was just curious if Parse does so when storing their information on Amazon's AWS servers.  I checked out the Privacy section at Parse.com and didn't get an answer.  I also tried searching for "data at rest", both here and at the google group, with no success.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this possibly a programming question?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really thinking :(  They moved their forums out to Google Groups and here.  Already had an account here so I posted it...

Comment: I've voted for this to be moved as well, so hopefully that will happen soon.  Would be handy if I could move this without just having to vote for it to be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It is encrypted whenever it travels over the wire (HTTPS), but not at rest.

You can encrypt the data and store it as you wish, but Parse does not automatically encrypt data for storage.